# linked SDL2 libs with GCC

Tags: c, linux, debian, sdl-2

im trying create a c program that include SDL2 libs but for some unknown reason i get error during compiling with sdl function, i explain myself :

- I have downloaded all required developper SDL2 packages with this command

  ```
  apt-get-install  libsdl2-dev libsdl2-gfx-dev libsdl2-image-dev libsdl2-mixer-dev 
  libsdl2-net-dev libsdl2-ttf-dev
  ```
- In my c file i put this at the top :

  ```
   #include <SDL2/SDL.h>
  ```
- to compile my code with gcc i linked it with `SDL2-config`  to add all missing libs etc.
  command i use :

  ```
  gcc   main.c  -o main.o `sdl2-config --cflags --libs`
  ```
- finally this is the code i want to compiled

  ```
  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
     SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO); 

     SDL_SetVideoMode(640, 480, 32, SDL_HWSURFACE); 

     SDL_Quit();

     return EXIT_SUCCESS; 
  }
  ```

this is the errors i get

```
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:19:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘SDL_SetVideoMode’; did you mean ‘SDL_GetVideoDriver’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   19 |     SDL_SetVideoMode(640, 480, 32, SDL_HWSURFACE); // Ouverture de la fenêtre
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |     SDL_GetVideoDriver
main.c:19:36: error: ‘SDL_HWSURFACE’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘SDL_SWSURFACE’?
   19 |     SDL_SetVideoMode(640, 480, 32, SDL_HWSURFACE); // Ouverture de la fenêtre
      |                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                    SDL_SWSURFACE
main.c:19:36: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
```

it seem like some libs has not been add or are missing but i think i  added  all of them.

Comment: If you want to use SDL 1.2 functions like `SDL_SetVideoMode()` why did you install SDL2?  SDL2 overhauled the API and that function no longer exists in it.

Comment: The code you're trying to compile was written for the ancient SDL1.2, while we already have SDL2. If you're following a tutorial, ditch it and find a better one.